# Через консоль добавить элемент в List

Tags: c#, list

Собственно я создал **List** с фильмами и мне нужно через консоль добавить новый фильм

В голову идей не приходит :(

Вот сам **List**:

```
public class Film
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Genre { get; set; }
            public int YearOfRelease { get; set; }
            public double Rating { get; set; }
            public int Price { get; set; }
        }

        public static List<Film> GetFilms()
        {
            List<Film> collectionOfFilms = new List<Film>
            {
                new Film{Name="Психо", Genre="Ужастик", YearOfRelease=1960, Price=400, Rating=8.9 },
                new Film{Name="Лига Справедливости", Genre="Фантастика", YearOfRelease=2021, Price=450, Rating=8.0 },
                new Film{Name="1917", Genre="Драма", YearOfRelease=2019, Price=320, Rating=7.9 },
                new Film{Name="8 Миля", Genre="Драма", YearOfRelease=2002, Price=500, Rating=7.7 },
                new Film{Name="Шоу Трумана", Genre="Фантастика", YearOfRelease=1998, Price=320, Rating=8.3 },
                new Film{Name="Милые Кости", Genre="Фэнтези", YearOfRelease=2009, Price=320, Rating=7.1 },
                new Film{Name = "Убийство", Genre = "Боевик", YearOfRelease = 2015, Price = 500, Rating = 7.1 },
                new Film{Name = "Куб", Genre = "Триллер", YearOfRelease = 1997, Price = 400, Rating = 7.2 },
                new Film{Name = "Довод", Genre = "Фантастика", YearOfRelease = 2020, Price = 500, Rating = 7.6 },
                new Film{Name = "Семь", Genre = "Триллер", YearOfRelease = 1995, Price = 500, Rating = 8.3 },
            };

            return collectionOfFilms;
        }
```

Comment: Создайте метод, который считывает по порядку все компоненты фильма и создает потом из них класс и возвращает готовый фильм в вызывающий метод.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
List<Film> films = new List<Film>();

for (int i =0; i<3; i++)
{
    Film newFilm = new Film();

    Console.WriteLine("Введите название:");
    newFilm.Name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Введите жанр:");
    newFilm.Genre = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Введите год:");
    newFilm.YearOfRelease = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Введите рейтинг:");
    newFilm.Rating = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Введите цену:");
    newFilm.Price = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    films.Add(newFilm);
}

foreach (Film film in films) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Название: {film.Name}, Жанр: {film.Genre}, год: {film.YearOfRelease}, рейтинг: {film.Rating}, цена: {film.Price}");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```